# JSF ActionListener always runs before Action - how can i switch language?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, web

this is what i am trying to do :

```
    <h:commandButton image="resources/frontend/img/persion.PNG" styleClass="persion"  action="#{language.changeLocaleCode('fa')}">
        <f:actionListener binding="#{home}" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

first change the language in my `LanguageBean` then call back bean of home.xhtml to load data according to new language.

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{language}")
private LanguageBean language;

public HomeView() implements ActionListener{

}


@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String lang = language.getReadableLang();
.
. // do DAO stuff whil lang
.


public void processAction(ActionEvent arg0) throws AbortProcessingException {
        init();

}
```

first i thought maybe if i put a Thread.sleep() command inside processAction i can postpone the listener's action until commandButton's action is done but that did not make any change. is there an other LanguageBean associated with HomeView or is it because HomeView's listener always runs before LanguageBean action? how can i make this work? is there any standard solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between action and actionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: Why do you need that action listener? If the Home bean is request or view scoped and you navigate to a new view (by returning non-`null`/`void`), then it's automagically reconstructed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is not duplicate. in some points it is similar bur not duplicate. i know some people just love to down vote

Comment: @BalusC thanks for reply. but my home bean is not constructing on every request (even after i changed it to requestScope) i am changing styles of the page with javascrip so the whole page is not reloading

Comment: @BalusC now i made some changes that make my whole page refreshes, but the problem is home bean is always initializing before language bean, it means before language bean changes its language home bean attacks it and grab the previous language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments I gather that the `#{home}` bean is request scoped and needs to be reconstructed when the language change has made. In that case, you should be redirecting back to the same view instead of navigating to the same view.

```
public String changeLocaleCode(String language) {
    // ...

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Then you can get rid of the `<f:actionListener>`.

Comment: although i lost few points because of down votes, but it surely worth it . thank you very much